# Text Index not return results according to language

Tags: mongodb, multilingual, fulltext-index

I create a collection links.
Every document has a field language.
When I try to search, full text search not working according to language.

I try with "it"/"en" and "italian/english" ( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages )
I try use language_override ( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#create-a-text-index-for-a-collection-in-multiple-languages )

```
use search

//Insert some data
db.links.insert({"language": "it", "content": "quando cammino ho male al ginocchio"})
db.links.insert({"language": "it", "content": "ho male alle ginocchia"})
db.links.insert({"language": "en", "content": "A lot of pain knee"})

//Create index
db.links.createIndex({content: "text"})

//Test search but with empty result
db.search.find({$text: {$search: "ginocchia"}})
//I try default english works
db.links.find({$text: {$search: "knee"}})

//So I drop indexes and try language_override
db.links.dropIndexes()
db.search.createIndex({content: "text"}, {language_override: "language"})

//Test search but with empty result
db.search.find({$text: {$search: "ginocchia"}})
//I try default english works
db.links.find({$text: {$search: "knee"}})

//If I set default_language in "it" working in italian and not in english.
```

I espect that if I insert "ginocchia" get firsts two documents, if I insert "knee" get the last.

Answer (score 0):

I use also $language in find and now it works